# React Native example of StackNavigator with multiple screens

Tags: react-native, stack-navigator

I can't seem to find an example of a react-native app that uses one or several stack navigators to drill down multiple screens.  The tutorials I've seen only goes from one Main Page to one Child Page.

I'd like to see an example of code on how you go from a Main Page, to Child Page, to a Grand Child Page.

Can anyone show sample code that does this?

I made an attempt to do it once, but ran into this issue here:

[StackNavigator can't nest multiple levels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46381715/stacknavigator-cant-nest-multiple-levels)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with the **react navigation**. You can go **nested** using the react navigation.I have used this and its working fine. When i tested your code given in the link above I found that there is a mistake you are making inside your code which produces this error not the react navigation. In your code for the **Regions** class inside your navigation options, you just declared a object style in the prop which takes the title with a string.

> [StackNavigator can't nest multiple levels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46381715/stacknavigator-cant-nest-multiple-levels)

Just check the answer for your above given question and try this, then it will work absolutely fine. I just ran your code and its good now :)